# Wave Dashboard Trailhead Challenge

Tags: einstein-analytics

[image]

Hi There,

Inorder to complete a trailhead challenge related to Wave Dashboards it required me to Sign-Up for a NEW Dev Org to be able to get access to Wave.
 I completed the Task, but looks like the system is unable to identify the ORG where I have completed my configuration.( Logged into Trailhead with my Dev Org where I have other Badges won already - System failed as the Org related to this Trail has'nt got Wave Access. Logged in as the new User with my brand new credentials - the system says "Howdy there, we see you are New here. If you have an existing trailhead Account please login using the existing credentails). Please help.

Comment: did you link it to the "special" wave dev org ?? normal dev org will not work for this.

Comment: Hi Vamsi, I figured this one out. All I needed to do was to "Link" the new Dev Org which has ot Sample Data for wave to my Trailhead Org. You can toggle between the Dev Orgs for challenges and the badges will Roll-Up into your main Account. Therefore regardless of where you complete your challenges, the Badges will always Add-Up.